# C# Insert with MS Access not inserting?

Tags: c#, ms-access, datagridview, insert

I'm trying to insert new rows to an Access database in C#.  The code compiles and supposedly inserts new data to the database, but there is no new data after the datagridview update. Also no new data on the database itself.

Sorry, I'm new with this, could someone help me?

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Data.OleDb;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Windows.Forms;

namespace WindowsFormsApplicaction1
{
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }
        OleDbConnection connect = new OleDbConnection();
        private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            this.articulosTableAdapter.Fill(this.inventarioDataSet.Articulos);
        }
        private void UpdateTable()
        {
            connect.ConnectionString = @"Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source=C:\Users\Kudox\Desktop\Inventario.accdb";
            connect.Open();
            OleDbCommand command = new OleDbCommand();
            command.Connection = connect;
            string query = "SELECT * from Articulos";
            command.CommandText = query;

            OleDbDataAdapter da = new OleDbDataAdapter(command);
            DataTable dt = new DataTable();
            da.Fill(dt);
            dataGridView1.DataSource = dt;
            connect.Close();
        }
        private void btnInsertar_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            connect.ConnectionString = @"Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source=C:\Users\Kudox\Desktop\Inventario.accdb";
            string Nombre;
            int Cantidad, CostoPU, Importancia, CostoTO;
            try
            {
                Nombre = txtNombre.Text;
                Cantidad = int.Parse(txtCantidad.Text);
                CostoPU = int.Parse(txtCosto.Text);
                Importancia = int.Parse(cmbImportancia.SelectedItem.ToString());
                CostoTO = CostoPU * Cantidad;
                connect.ConnectionString = @"Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source=C:\Users\Kudox\Desktop\Inventario.accdb";
                OleDbCommand cmd = new OleDbCommand("INSERT into Articulos(NombreArticulo, CostoPorUnidad, CantidadDeArticulos, Importancia, CostoTotal) values('"+Nombre+"','" + CostoPU +"','" + Cantidad +"','" + Importancia +"','" + CostoTO +"')");
                MessageBox.Show("Articulo agregado");
                UpdateTable();
            }
            catch(Exception err)
            {
                MessageBox.Show(err.Message);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Add cmd.ExecuteNonQuery(); before showing message

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After setting your datasource, you need to databind, so within your UpdateTable() procedure, after `dataGridView1.DataSource = dt;`, add:

```
dataGridView1.DataBind();
```

As far as your insert command, you need to execute it at some point (probably right after your `OleDbCommand cmd = ...` line), something like:

```
cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
```